# I am sending attachments in the messages but the messages.attachements isn't showing any attachments in my discord js bot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

This is the code for messageCreate event that I wrote:

[image]

And in the discord app I am getting the response of the console log for no attachments even though I have tried sending images text and audio files:

[image]

Comment: message.attachments is an array, try checking message.attachments.length == 0 instead of message.attachments.size === 0.

Comment: i tried and also tried console logging message.attachments it printed out ''Collection(0) [Map] {}""  so that means it really did'nt read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely missing the `MESSAGE_CONTENT` intent.

Go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and enable the `Message Content Intent` in the Bot section.

Image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVSXE.jpg

Also make sure to add the `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` when you define your client.

Comment: I tried it......stilll not reading the attachments

Comment: can you attach a snippet of how you defined your client?

Comment: Actually I forgot to add MessageContent in client! .......... worked it out though, thanks